# Git rollback push, .gitignore - ignored

Tags: git

I have some problem with git. I have a file .gitignore with content:

```
uploads
.htaccess
robots.txt
etc..
```

I did:

```
 git commit -a -m "GIT TEST"
```

And git sent my files: .htaccess and other (in .gitignore). Why ? How can I cancel this commit ? (commit is pushed to repo "git push origin master")

Answer (score 0):

If a file was already being tracked by `git` before it was added to `.gitignore`, it won't be automatically ignored just because it's in `.gitignore` now. You'll need to

```
git rm --cached .htaccess
git commit
```

to tell `git` to stop tracking that file. You can do that on the next commit and push cycle, but if you really need to amend the most recent commit to remove the file, you can do this:

```
git rm --cached .htaccess
git commit --amend
git push -f
```

(but beware if others might have already fetched the "bad" commit - this will cause them grief). If the commit in question isn't the most recent one, but is farther back in history, you can accomplish the same thing with `git filter-branch` (examples of the exact syntax should be pretty easy to find) followed by `git push -f`, but the same caveats apply.